# SPD 2010 workflow, update (add and delete) lookup column

Tags: designer-workflow, lookup-column

I have a list (with a custom InfoPath form) in which I have items that have a Parent / Child relationship with two lookup column to the title column of same list. The two lookups are "Child of" single values only, and "Parent Of" multi-select values. I am currently handling the relationship from the child side and have been able to sucessfuly create a workflow in SPD to update the parent item "Parent Of" column for each child as the relationship is created (selected in the Child) by pulling in the Parent "Parent Of" and appending the ID;#Title and then re-seting the "Parent Of" field. The problem I am having is when a Child is updated to either have a different or no parent. I need to remove or uncheck one of the multi-select boxes. My thought was to pull in the "Parent Of" from the Parent as a string and the somehow remove the appropriate ID;#Title from the string, but cannot figure out how to do this.

I would be open to handling this from the Parent and then updating each Child accordingly but since a "For Each" function is not in SPD 2010, I am not sure how I would handle this.

FYI - To my knowledge I cannot use any codeplex solutions as I do not have server access.